# Syntax for using FactoryGirl with belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I can't get the syntax right when using FactoryGirl with a `belongs_to` relation.

I have a schema that includes:

```
create_table "region_classifiers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "is_default"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "regions", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "region_classifier_id"
end
```

My `Region` model is:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :region_classifier
end
```

My factories are:

```
factory :region_classifier do
    name 'classifier 1'
    is_default false
end

factory :region do
    name 'region 1'
    region_classifier
end
```

I can create a region just fine with

```
Region.create(name: 'Bar', region_classifier: RegionClassifier.first)
```

But when I invoke `FactoryGirl.create(:region)` I get an error:

```
can't write unknown attribute `region_classifier_id' (ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError)
```

Presumably I'm misreading the FactoryGirl documentation somehow, but how do I get it to create the region?

**Edit:**

Oh well, never mind. I needed to keep things moving so I rolled back the database to undo a series of changes to `Region`, destroyed the scaffold, deleted the migrations, then created a new scaffold based on the current version of what I want region to be. It works now, so clearly one of my migrations didn't do what I wanted it to.

Comment: have you prepared your test DB? (`rake test:prepare`)

Comment: Yes. I've run rake:test:prepare again just in case, but no change.